# Haskell Recursive Type Classes

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I want to create a recursive instance type based on tuples. What I am looking for is something similar than this:

```hs
class Provider a b where
  getInstance :: a -> b

instance Provider a b => Provider (x, a) b where
  getInstance (x, a) = getInstance a

instance Provider (b, x) b where
  getInstance (b, _) = b

tryFunc1 :: Int
tryFunc1 =
  let provider = ("test", (10, ())) :: (String, (Int, ()))
  in getInstance provider

tryFunc2 :: String
tryFunc2 =
  let provider = ("test", (10, ())) :: (String, (Int, ()))
  in getInstance provider
```

Unfortunatelly, haskell fails to solve the instance. Any reason?

Comment: Presumably you want Haskell to use the first instance over the second one when possible. Unfortunately, when trying to decide which instance to use when there are multiple candidates, GHC only looks at the instance head to try to determine which is most specific.

Comment: But in the cases I wrote, the decision should be deterministic, as in the tryFunc2 the second instance is the only that has String as the second type argument, and in the case of tryFunc1 is the combination of the first one and the second one. There is only one possible solution.

Comment: @FernandoRincon The design of Haskell's typeclass system guarantees much more than merely a unique solution: it guarantees that the solution can be found without doing a (backtracking) search. This is an efficiency vs. expressiveness tradeoff, and in my opinion it has served the language well. Your proposed instances would, in general, require the compiler to do search to find the solution, even if it is unique -- and so are rejected.

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to stop using the deprecated `OverlappingInstances` pragma and start using the per instance `OVERLAPPING` and `OVERLAPPABLE` pragmas. With just this change:

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Provider a b => Provider (x, a) b where
  getInstance (x, a) = getInstance a

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Provider (b, x) b where
  getInstance (b, _) = b
```

I get `tryFunc1` to be `10` and `tryFunc2` to be `"test"`.

---

Technically you only need either the `OVERLAPPABLE` or `OVERLAPPING` pragma, but I believe that it is good practice to have both in this case... Also, I suppose this is the behaviour that you want, but note that this just gets the *first* of whatever type you are looking for (so `getInstance  (10, (20, ())) :: Int` gives me `10` and *not* `20`)

Good source of info is the [ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9242) tracking the feature's creation.

Answer (score 1):

I know some people don't like `UndecidableInstances` but that's what I like to do in this type of situation: use a closed `type family` to make it explicit that the choice is fully deterministic.

The idea is to have the type family compute a boolean flag making it clear which branch should be taken by the typeclass resolution mechanism. The `UndecidableInstance` extension is needed because of the `Provider a b (AtHead a b) =>` constraint even though it's harmless.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables   #-}

module Provider where

import Data.Proxy
import Data.Type.Equality

class Provider a b (f :: Bool) where
  getInstance' :: Proxy f -> a -> b

type family AtHead x y :: Bool where
  AtHead (x, a) y = x == y

instance Provider a b (AtHead a b) => Provider (x, a) b 'False where
  getInstance' _ (x, a) = getInstance' (Proxy :: Proxy (AtHead a b)) a

instance Provider (b, x) b 'True where
  getInstance' _ (b, _) = b

getInstance :: forall a b. Provider a b (AtHead a b) => a -> b
getInstance = getInstance' (Proxy :: Proxy (AtHead a b))

tryFunc1 :: Int
tryFunc1 =
  let provider = ("test", (10, ())) :: (String, (Int, ()))
  in getInstance provider

tryFunc2 :: String
tryFunc2 =
  let provider = ("test", (10, ())) :: (String, (Int, ()))
  in getInstance provider
```

Comment: thanks for the replay. Do you see any benefit from your implementation compared to Alec 's implementation?

Comment: I don't know much about the pragmas Alec uses but the distinction between overlapping and overlappable leads me to believe that it's a way to describe the order in which solutions should be tried. There seem to be 2 cases: the base one (overlappable) and the special one (overlapping).

With a type family, you could have more flexibility i.e. not just 2 alternatives but 3 or more. E.g. [in this instance](https://gist.github.com/gallais/3b7c7d9488b25978caa278bc18617f79), you check not only the left but also the right component of the product for equality. `tryFunc3` showcases that new ability.